# setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(int idx) for JLabel containing HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I am trying to create a `JLabel` that consists of HTML text in it with a mnemonic. It worked fine. I was able to grab the focus for the component for which the label was set.

But i couldn't see an underline under the specified mnemonic index. Here is a code excerpt

```
JLabel l=new JLabel("<html><h2>Label 8</h2></html>");
l.setDisplayedMnemonic('8');
l.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(16);
```

Except the answer that manually underlining using HTML like

```
JLabel l=new JLabel("<html><h2>Label <u>8</u></html>");
```

Is there any alternative way?

By the way, i did not get an `IllegalArgumentException`

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: I copied your code exactly and it ran fine.

Comment: What ran fine? You mean the underline?

Comment: Yes. http://i.imgur.com/88uB9eq.png

Comment: Hmm, You might have tried the `JLabel l=new JLabel("<html><h2>Label <u>8</u></h2></html>");` Unfortunately, that is not the way i asked.

Comment: I tried this: `<html><h2>Label <u>8</u></html>`, as in your second example.

Comment: The one you just gave me ran fine also.

Comment: (simple curiosity) please for why reason are there setDisplayedMnemonic(Xxx)

Comment: Hmm. Good question ;) Probably to indicate the user when he presses Alt with the combination of the underlined, he gets the focus of the component associated with it.

Comment: JLabel isn't focusable JComponent, by default never to react to KeyEvent (ATL Key), then could be to crazy to write AWTEventListener for Key & Mouse Events in JLabel

Comment: It is focusable component. Try calling isFocusable() on JLabel when you create it. Also setFocusable() works as well, the thing is you don't see the focus painted by default. One more thing is that the setLabelFor() method takes a Component on which requestFocus() is called. When the user hits the mnemonic with an alt key pressed, the component associated with the label gets the focus.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any alternative way?

Sure.  Instead of using HTML in the component, just set a large `Font`.  If using HTML, expect odd quirks like that.

Comment: Well that's a cool idea but i would just like to know whether it is a bug?

Comment: (shrugs) It depends who you ask. But given Oracle has no intention of fixing the fact that HTML renders wrong if the component is disabled, I'd say they have even less motivation to fix this one.  So does it really matter if it is technically a 'bug'?

Answer (score 0):

With a quick look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setDisplayedMnemonicIndex%28int%29), an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown if the index is equal to the length of it's contents or if it is less than -1. Your `JLabel` technically only contains this string: "Label 8". The HTML content **is not included**. Therefore, your given index, 16, is greater than the length of the string, 8, which will in turn throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Nope. The text in it technically is not Label 8. It is the whole HTML Text.